# How to stop overriding portal-ext file?

Tags: liferay, portal

I have this issue which I am unable to fix. I have an ext-plugin which overrides my *portal-ext.rpoperties* file (and I don't want this overriding) with another blank *portal-ext* file. There is no *portal-ext.properties* file in my ext-plugin but still every time when I deploy, this happens.

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see in log during portal starting that yout portal-ext is loaded?

Comment: create portal-ext file in your ext and paste your ext settings there.hope your problem will resolved

Comment: EXT's portal-ext.properties must always over-ride properties of Portal's portal-ext.properties. Therefore, If you have created plugin-ext, you must add portal-ext.properties file in it otherwise it will keep on over-riding with empty file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the response which i got from Liferay support department and it solves my problem. I am sharing here so it could be helpful to any other.

---

> "Where is the portal-ext.properties file located in your system?
>
> In WEB-INF/classes or in ${liferay.home}/portal-ext.properties?"

If it's in WEB-INF/classes, simply move your portal-ext.properties into *${liferay.home}/portal-ext.properties* location. If it's the same, you can place your *portal-ext.properties* into your EXT plugin, so the original will be copied into the system instead of the empty one.

You can also add include-and-override lines in the empty *portal-ext.properties* and rename your original file to be loaded after *portal-ext.properties*, or you can use different properties file and specify it to the JVM to load. See the relevant part from portal.properties file:

Properties Override

```
#
# Specify where to get the overridden properties. Updates should not be made
# on portal.properties or on portal-bundle.properties, but in
# portal-ext.properties.
#
# The default read order is: portal.properties, portal-bundle.properties,
# portal-ext.properties, and then portal-setup-wizard.properties.
#
include-and-override=portal-bundle.properties
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/portal-bundle.properties
include-and-override=portal-ext.properties
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/portal-ext.properties
include-and-override=portal-setup-wizard.properties
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/portal-setup-wizard.properties

#
# Each portal instance can have its own overriden property file following
# the convention portal-companyWebId.properties. To enable this feature, set
# the "company-id-properties" system property to true.
#
# To enable:
#
#     java ... -Dcompany-id-properties=true
#
# The read order will now be: portal.properties, then portal-ext.properties,
# and then portal-liferay.com.properties.
#
# Note that not all properties can have different values per company. This
# functionality is only available for legacy reasons. The preferred way to
# configure a portal instance is through the Control Panel.
#
include-and-override=portal-${easyconf:companyId}.properties
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/portal-${easyconf:companyId}.properties

#
# Additional property files can be used by setting the "external-properties"
# system property.
#
# A common use case is to keep legacy property values when upgrading to
# newer versions of Liferay. To enable:
#
#     java ... -Dexternal-properties=portal-legacy-5.1.properties
#
# The read order will now be: portal.properties, then portal-ext.properties,
# and then portal-legacy-5.1.properties.
#
include-and-override=${external-properties}
include-and-override=${liferay.home}/${external-properties}
```